# Regasm in code (dynamic register)

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, com

*How can I register a COM-visible assembly in code like REGASM?*

**Background:**
I have to deploy a dll with a legacy Delphi 5 application, but the DLL is C# written and made COM Visible.

Is there a way I can replicate this functionality dynamically in code (regasm xxx.dll), as the legacy application is launched from a network path (no local installation on all the clients).

Thanks

Comment: Registration free COM?

Comment: Can't you just run regasm? Why replicate its functionality when its functionality is already there?

Comment: I do not have access to all the users of the application and their geographically spread. I'd take the easy option if I could :|

Comment: @DaneBalia - what's the relation between the users of the application, their geography and the regasm tool? Why can't you use regasm exactly?

Comment: Because regasm needs to be run locally for every user of the application. I do not have access to the machines.

Comment: At the point in your program where you plan to "replicate" regasm, just *run* it instead. And please remember to use `@` when replying so we'll be notified of your comments.

Comment: @ Apologies! That's what I was thinking, to call regasm manually. Was trying to avoid this due to possible permission problems. Thanks I have two ideas to try ;)

Comment: What permissions problems? You think that by using something other than `regasm` you'll magically be able to write to the COM registry in HKLM? If `regasm` cannot do it, why would anything be able to?

Comment: @ Yes there are two methods available to me outside the obvious. (A) Registration-free COM (as per Microsoft) (B) Create a regfile using regasm and deploy that. Permissions problems - as in don't have permissions to run regasm on client and alter the GAC.

Comment: I expected someone who's been using comments for over a year would have figured out how replying works. *Merely* typing `@` isn't sufficient to notify anyone. Click the "help" link next to the comment edit box and read what it has to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use the `/regfile` command line option to `regasm`, then execute the generated `.reg` file.

I prefer using `reg.exe import "%s"` instead of `regedit.exe`, since it will avoid a popup. Or you can write your own .reg parser and update the registry, but it may be overcomplicated.

Ensure every `"CodeBase"="file://...."` entry will be changed to expected (network) folder containing the COM `.dll` wrapper.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot imagine why it would be preferable to shell out to `reg` rather than calling `regasm` directly.

Comment: In fact, I sometimes used this to register some COM objects for the actual user only by using HKEY_CURRENTUSER instead of HKEY_LOCALMACHINE: in this case, administrator rights are not needed. This works even when Registration-free COM fails, due to security reasons.  But `regasm` is the normal way, by design.